# how to Print list inside [ ] using nested for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm curious about how to print the list using nested.

here's the code

```
students = [["BSIT",["JOSHUA", "CRISA", "JAYMARK"]], ["BSCS",["BOBS", "CARLO", "GERALD"]]]
 
for i,j in students:
    print (i,"\n-",j)
```

when I try to print it,

```
BSIT 
- ['JOSHUA', 'CRISA', 'JAYMARK']
BSCS 
- ['BOBS', 'CARLO', 'GERALD']
>
```

How can I print element inside the "BSIT" individually? Is there any wrong syntax?

Comment: Another loop over `j`…‽

Comment: you probably need to use `print (i, "\n-", *j)` or if you need each oe on its own line, something in the form of `print (i,"\n-".join([""]+j))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the syntax, the logic of the code doesn't match with what you are trying to do. Each element in `students` is in the form of a [String, List]. And within the list contains the students names. If you want to print out the students names, you can do using the following code:

```
for i,j in students:
    print(i)
    for name in j:
        print("\t", name)
```

The code will retrieve each element and store the String as i and the List as j. We can then iterate through the List and display each of its element as shown.

```
for i,j in students:
    print(i)
    print(*j)
```

You can also use the code above to display all the contents of the list within a single line as pointed out by Onyambu.

Comment: I thought it's impossible to name the 'list' like naming the 'j' as name. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Carlmalone They're just used to reference items so you can name them as anything you want!